# Exception on sending sms from Java web application using Twilio sms api

Tags: java, twilio

I am working on Java Web application. I have to send sms using Twilio sms api through this application.
Here is the sample code which I am using.

```
public class Example {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"; 
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"; 
    public static void main(String[]args) throws TwilioRestException { 
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "twilioNumber"));    
        MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
        Message message = messageFactory.create(params); 
    } 
 }
```

I have added all the credentials in the respective field ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN and twilioNumber.
But this code throws exception as

```
Exception in thread "main" com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException: A 'To' phone number is required.
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioRestException.parseResponse(TwilioRestException.java:74)
    at com.twilio.sdk.TwilioClient.safeRequest(TwilioClient.java:497)
    at com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.MessageList.create(MessageList.java:70)
    at com.twilio.Example.main(Example.java:54)
```

I am unable to figure out what should be given in 'To' phone number as I want to send sms 
through my web application and not through a phone number. Please guide me how to proceed.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the API but it seems like you just have to add a param like

new BasicNameValuePair("**To**", "receivernumber");
 the following tutorial is in c# wich has nearly equal Syntax, so maybe it helps http://www.markhagan.me/Samples/Receive_SMS_Text_Using_Twilio_ASPNet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This link was quite useful. I will try to implement accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I have implemented using BasicNameValuePair. 
    I have added Twilio number in 'From' parameter and a verified number from Twilio as 'To' parameter.
    I am posting sample working code below if it can help someone.

```
public class Example {
    public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"; 
    public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"; 

    public static void main(String[]args) throws TwilioRestException { 
        TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "To_number"));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "Twilio_number"));  
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Sent from Twilio!"));
        MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
        Message message = messageFactory.create(params); 
        try {
            Message sms = messageFactory.create(params);
            } catch (TwilioRestException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside exception!!");
            }
    } 
}
Thanks for your help.
```